# XSLT Tokenize output as numbers

Tags: xml, xslt, string-formatting, number-formatting, integer-arithmetic

In the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="input">
    <xsl:variable name="n" select="tokenize(./text(),'[0-9]+([,.][0-9]+)?')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="(($n[0]*$n[0]+$n[1]*$n[1])/(n[3]*($n[0]*$n[0]+$n[1]*$n[1])))>300">
            Retina!
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            Trash!
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example input:

```
<input>1920 1400 0.425</input>
```

I use `tokenize` to match some numbers in between two `input` tags. The only problem is that resulting list of numbers are all formatted as strings, and so fail the maths later in the code.

So, is there a way to get tokenizer to output a list of numbers, or alternatively is there an equivalent of `map` in XSLT 2.0?

**Note:** I am using the Saxon processor

Comment: Could you post an example of the input, so that we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Sure

Comment: Consider to explain what you want to achieve, which output do you want to create for the input you posted? Your code does not explain that to me as `$n[0]` does not make sense in XSLT/XPath where the index of items in a sequence starts with `1`. And to get a sequence of numbers with your input `1920 1400 0.425` I would simply expect the use of `tokenize(., '\s+')`, if you use a regular expression matching the numbers as the second argument then the returned sequence contains the strings between numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there a way to get tokenizer to output a list of numbers

Yes. For example, you could do:

```
<xsl:variable name="n" select="for $i in tokenize($input, $pattern) return number($i)"/>
```

Note, however that:

1. Your tokenizing pattern does not return the expected values;
2. In XPath, nodes are numbered from 1; `$n[0]` is empty and any
   numerical operation using it will result in `NaN`.

Comment: @BetaDecay PHP? No, that's XSLT which in turn uses XPath.

Comment: No, no I mean the `for $i in tokenize`

Comment: @BetaDecay An XSLT processor uses an XSLT stylesheet, written in the XSLT language.  The XSLT language "*is designed to be used in conjunction with XPath*". No other languages are recognized (unless your processor supports them as an extension - e.g. Saxon will allow you to borrow from Java). The expression `for $i in ... return ...` is in XPath - see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#id-for-expressions